# Nested insert SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

I am using MS sql as a database. I want to write an nested query for that. My query is:

```
INSERT INTO [Node-churn](total_amount_in)  values=
       (SELECT sum(cast(amount as float)) 
        FROM [CDR-IN] 
        WHERE [Node-churn].subscriber=[CDR-IN].callee) 
WHERE degree <6
```

I got error for running this query. What would be the correct query for this problem?

P.S: `Node-churn=(subscribers,degree)`, `CDR-IN=(caller,callee,amount)`

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of what the `select` statement would be:

```
insert into [Node-churn](total_amount_in)
    select sum(cast(amount as float))
    from [CDR-IN]
    where [Node-churn].subscriber = [CDR-IN].callee and degree < 6;
```

But I think you want an `update`:

```
update [Node-churn]
    set total_amount_in = (select sum(cast(amount as float))
                           from [CRD-IN]
                           where [Node-churn].subscriber = [CDR-IN].callee
                          )
    where degree < 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use WHERE in an insert query. Maybe it's a typo, and the correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO [Node-churn](total_amount_in)  values= 
   (SELECT sum(cast(amount as float)) 
    FROM [CDR-IN] 
    WHERE [Node-churn].subscriber=[CDR-IN].callee and degree <6
)
```